# Let $\bar{A}=(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)$. Prove that (i) $I+\bar{A}$ is non-singular (ii) $\bar{\bar{A}}=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ be a square matrix such that $I+A$ is non-singular. Let $\bar{A}=(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)$. Prove that (i) $I+\bar{A}$ is non-singular (ii) $\bar{\bar{A}}=A$.

Please suggest me a guideline to solve it.

Comment: Please review [ask].  I suspect that you have ideas about how to solve at least parts of this (multi-part) Question, and it is helpful to your Readers to know what you have already worked out (or at least where you got stuck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
I+\bar{A}
&=I+(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)\\[6px]
&=(I+A)^{-1}(I+A)+(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)\\[6px]
&=(I+A)^{-1}(I+A+I-A)\\[6px]
&=2(I+A)^{-1}
\end{align}
Next,
$$
\bar{\bar{A}}=(I+\bar{A})^{-1}(I-\bar{A})
$$
Since you know that
$$
(I+\bar{A})^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(I+A)
$$
and
$$
I-\bar{A}=I-(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)
$$
we have
\begin{align}
\bar{\bar{A}}
&=(I+\bar{A})^{-1}(I-\bar{A}) \\[6px]
&=\frac{1}{2}(I+A)(I-\bar{A}) \\[6px]
&=\frac{1}{2}(I+A)(I-(I+A)^{-1}(I-A))\\[6px]
&=\frac{1}{2}(I+A-I+A)
\end{align}

Comment: for the second part, $\bar{\bar{A}}=(I+\bar{A})^{-1}(I-\bar{A})=\frac{1}{2}(I+A)(I-\bar{A})=\frac{1}{2}(I+A-\bar{A}-A\bar{A})$ then how to get the desired result?

Comment: @user1942348 Just do the math. `;-)` I added the steps

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is great.

Answer (score 0):

1)We notice that $ \frac{I+A}{2}$ $\bar{A}$=I.So the inverse matrix of $\bar{A}$ is actually $\frac{I+A}{2}$. 
   2)I think you can represent $(I+\bar{A})^{-1}$ as $\frac{I+A}{2}$ and verify the equation.
   Hope that will help you.This is my first time to answer a question,could you tell me how to start a new line?

Comment: the inverse matrix of $I+\bar{A}$,I type wrong.

Comment: How $\frac{I+A}{2}\bar{A}=I$? I think it is not right.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You may put two space at the end of the line to start a new line.

Comment: I am sorry for It is my first time to use Latex.I think I mean $\frac{I+A}{2}(I+\bar{A})=I$,then it makes sense.

Comment: It should be said that it's an extension of [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform) with its well known involutivity property.